# flashing images tableview reuse bug see the video link -->http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwEsqjc9sNc&feature=youtu.be

Tags: ios, tableview, reusability

here's the code : i am downloading  image from  my core data on background and put it on my image view.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Pubs Cell";
PubsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

Pub *current = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.name.text = current.name;
cell.description.text = current.descriptionText;
cell.description.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.description.editable = NO;
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("image_queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",current.photo]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        cell.pubImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light1.jpg"]];

return cell;
```

any ideas how to fix that? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the image to nil before you start the async loading-task:

```
// removing the old image from the reused tablecell
cell.pubImage.image = nil;

// load image asynchronously
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("image_queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",current.photo]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.pubImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});
```

This is because loading an image takes some time so you see the old one since tablecells are reused when available.